# XML Animation executing synced

Tags: android, android-animation

I've made some simple animations which I called breath because the object slowly get bigger and smaller in a loop.
Then I associated this animation to 3 imagebuttons and everything works ok, but when I interact with a button, which do another "vibrate" animation, all of them restart the animation together, while the expected behaviour was that only the pressed button would have restarted the animation.

I would like to understand that a bit better, and maybe how to achieve that every button's animation have its own lifecycle.

That's the code:

breath.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"  >

<scale
    android:duration="1500"
    android:startOffset="0"
    android:fromXScale="0.9"
    android:fromYScale="0.9"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:repeatCount="infinite" />

</set>
```

and that's the java code:

```
package com.anesoft.android.citmania;

import com.anesoft.android.citmania.models.Defines;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MenuActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, AnimationListener {
    
    ImageButton opzioni;
    ImageButton play;
    ImageButton espansioni;
    
    ImageView logo;
    
    TextView title,title2;
    
    Animation breath,rotate_r,rotate_l,vibrate;
    int flag = 0;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
        
        logo = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.logo);
        title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);
        title2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title2);
        opzioni = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.options);
        play = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.play);
        espansioni = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.expansions);
        
        breath = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.breath);
        rotate_r = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.rotate_right);
        rotate_l = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.rotate_left);
        vibrate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.vibrate);
        
        vibrate.setAnimationListener(this);
        
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/Canter_Light.otf");
        Typeface tf2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/Canter Bold.otf");
        
        title.setTypeface(tf);
        title2.setTypeface(tf2);
        
        title.setText("CIT");
        title.setTextSize(Defines.TITLE_SIZE);
        
        title2.setText(".MANIA");
        title2.setTextSize(Defines.TITLE_SIZE);
        
        
        
        opzioni.startAnimation(breath);
        play.startAnimation(breath);
        espansioni.startAnimation(breath);
        
        logo.setOnClickListener(this);
        opzioni.setOnClickListener(this);
        play.setOnClickListener(this);
        espansioni.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();
        if (id == R.id.options) {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, OptionsActivity.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            startActivity(i);
        } else if (id == R.id.play) {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, LevelPickerActivity.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            startActivity(i);
        } else if(id == R.id.expansions){
            espansioni.startAnimation(vibrate);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Implementando", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //espansioni.startAnimation(bounce);
        }else if(id == R.id.logo){
            if(flag==0){
                logo.startAnimation(rotate_r);
                flag=1;
            }else{
                logo.startAnimation(rotate_l);
                flag=0;
            }
        }
        
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
        if (arg0 == vibrate) {
            espansioni.startAnimation(breath);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

}
```

You can see how I start the vibrate animation and then when IT finishes I restart the breath one only in the button being tapped, but all of them restart the animation in a synced way.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the animation to work independently on all 3 buttons, you'll need to create 3 instances of the animation.

Once the animation is halted, it gives its views a new state. If you gave 3 views the same animation, they will all receive the new state.